# broad question.. making a CMS for article postings

Tags: php

This is a very broad question, so I expect a pretty broad answer.

I have created websites where an admin can post articles, however they would fall into a specific format.  for example

title, date, image, article body

What sort of techniques would I use to make a system where an admin could post the elements in an article in different combinations.

title, date, image, code, body, code, image, image, code, body

something like that?  Obviously if the person knew html they could just write it all manually, but what techniques do movie review websites, or news websites use in order to allow articles of different forms to be posted.

Comment: Did you look at how this site or the hundreds of forums out there do it?

Comment: This is a not a question that can be answered here. Refer to http://stackoverflow.com/faq#questions.  Did you do your homework before asking this question? I can suggest you many OpenSource CMS framework, Joomla!, Drupal and WordPress to name few.

Comment: i'm asking from scratch.  not using a framework

Comment: allow them to post html? and use a wysiwyg editor? see wordpress

Comment: If you'd read the FAQ you'd know that a "very broad question" is not appropriate here. Stack Overflow is for specific, answerable questions. The best you're going to get here is "go look at how it's been done elsewhere". See WordPress.

Comment: I believe the question you are actually asking boils down to a suitable database scheme. You shouldn't have written "broad question" in the title, as that just makes people jump to conclusions.

Comment: "Your questions should be reasonably scoped."  I believe this is a reasonably scoped question.

Comment: i guess ill check out wordpress and see how it does it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usual WebCMS do not have a flexible structure like that, but multiple database content tables and output plugins etc. to combine articles with images and a comment section for example. And more usually you only have a single body/content field for each article/page, with images or other content just assigned by reference and stored elsewhere.

However if you really insist, you could create a database scheme which is made up of core fields (title, date, id) and a separate list of page "attachments". The attachment table would have a reference (id) to the core article/page table with the meta fields, and attach either a type=body or type=image or type=code or type=comment block. Basically something like:

```
TABLE content (
     id INT,
     date DATETIME,
     title VARCHAR
)
TABLE attachments (
     id INT F_K,
     type ENUM (body, image, code, comment),
     data TEXT,
     outputposition INT
)
```

However that's really unusual, as it's more overhead than necessary. The common approach is to constraint the page types and structure, and use individual output handlers or indeed completed html pages.

Comment: thanks for giving me a solution and not problems =)